# WMI methods using ManagementObject.InvokeMethod()

Tags: c#, wmi

I am having issues when tyring to invoke the [SoftwareLicensingProduct.GetTokenActivationGrants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd637978%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WMI method using a .NET *ManagementObject* object. *GetTokenActivationGrants* has the following signature:

```c
uint32 GetTokenActivationGrants(
  [out]  string Grants[]
);
```

I'm using the following C# code:

```cs
class Program
{
    private const string GRANTS_METHOD = "GetTokenActivationGrants";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        ManagementObjectSearcher productSearch = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT ID, Name, ApplicationId, PartialProductKey, Description, LicenseIsAddon " +
            "FROM SoftwareLicensingProduct WHERE ApplicationId = '55c92734-d682-4d71-983e-d6ec3f16059f' AND PartialProductKey <> NULL " +
            "AND LicenseIsAddon = FALSE");

        foreach (ManagementObject product in productSearch.Get())
        {
            ManagementBaseObject inParams = product.GetMethodParameters(GRANTS_METHOD);
            ManagementBaseObject outParams = product.InvokeMethod(GRANTS_METHOD, inParams, null);
        }

    }
}
```

This fails with a **System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException** which I believe is occurring because the *GetMethodParameters* returns null. Does anyone know how to properly invoke a method like this that has a referenced argument?

Comment: The COMException class has a property called ErrorCode. What ErrorCode do you get?

Comment: The ErrorCode is -1073417466.

Comment: This error means the following: The Software Licensing Service reported that this software edition does not support token-based activation.

Comment: Thanks @Hans I was just able to figure this out myself. Did you find a listing of error codes anywhere? I was only able to find it in `%SystemRoot%\System32\slmgr\0409\slmgr.ini`.

Comment: Here is a link to error codes: http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/68b80aba-130d-4ad4-aa45-832b1ee49602

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Hans commented, this is an expected error. The problem is that none of the expected or possible errors are documented anywhere in the MSDN library. With a little digging you can find them in `%SystemRoot%\System32\slmgr\0409\slmgr.ini` or http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/68b80aba-130d-4ad4-aa45-832b1ee49602.