# How to programatically remove the Windows product key from registry in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, vbscript, license-key

How could I programatically remove the Windows product key from registry in .NET (C# or VB.NET) to reproduce the same effect as when calling the Microsoft's legit **slmgr.vbs** script file with the `/cpky` argument?... so please do not misunderstand in my question "remove" for "uninstall". I just want to remove the bytes that correspond to the product key of Windows that is stored and encoded in the `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion`: `DigitalProductId` registry value, so the product key still installed but it becomes inaccessible for 3rd party applications like [ProduKey](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/product_cd_key_viewer.html).

I tried to inspect the **slmgr.vbs** script file (stored at **C:\Windows\System32**) and it leads me to this method block:

```
Private Sub ClearPKeyFromRegistry()
    Dim objService

    On Error Resume Next

    set objService = GetServiceObject("Version")
    QuitIfError()

    objService.ClearProductKeyFromRegistry()
    QuitIfError()

    LineOut GetResource("L_MsgClearedPKey")
End Sub
```

However I'm a little bit lost trying to find and to understand from where comes and what it does the `GetServiceObject("Version")` call, since it seems not to be a built-in VBS member neither it doesn't seem to be declared as any local member in the script file, and I didn't found any info regarding "GetServiceObject" on MSDN docs/VBS reference.

PS: Please note that I won't depend on the existance of the **slmgr.vbs** file to solve this issuea by simply calling that script file from C#...

### UPDATE

I just scanned for the string "**ClearProductKeyFromRegistry**" in the dll files of the Windows filesystem, and found it in the **sppwmi.dll** file but unfortunately the function is not exported, then following with a simple research on Google it leads me to the **[ClearProductKeyFromRegistry method of the SoftwareLicensingService class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc534586(v=vs.85).aspx)** on MSDN, but now I don't know how do I use that. I tried to find info about how to use a existing WMI provider in .NET, but all the info I see around the WWW is about how to implement/create a WMI provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that same script you will find the `GetServiceObject` method (and the constants and globals it uses). To find them, search for the following terms in the script:

> - Function GetServiceObject
> - ServiceClass =
> - g_objWMIService =
> - L_MsgClearedPKey =

So it's just a matter of tracing the code and converting the lines. Here's what I came up with for the full `VBScript` version of the method and it's dependencies:

```
private const L_MsgClearedPKey = "Product key from registry cleared successfully."
private const ServiceClass = "SoftwareLicensingService"

g_strComputer = "."
Set g_objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & g_strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Private Sub ClearPKeyFromRegistry()  
    Dim objService

    On Error Resume Next

    set objService = GetServiceObject("Version")
    QuitIfError()

    objService.ClearProductKeyFromRegistry()
    QuitIfError()

    LineOut GetResource("L_MsgClearedPKey")
End Sub

Function GetServiceObject(strQuery)
    Dim objService
    Dim colServices

    On Error Resume Next

    Set colServices = g_objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT " & strQuery & 
        " FROM " & ServiceClass)
    QuitIfError()

    For each objService in colServices
        QuitIfError()
        Exit For
    Next

    QuitIfError()

    set GetServiceObject = objService
End Function
```

Next step is to reduce this down into one method. I went ahead and removed all the `QuitIfError()` calls and the `On Error Resume Next`, since we can just wrap our code in a `try/catch` block. After replacing the constants and globals, and combining the methods, I came up with this:

```
Dim objService
Dim colServices
Dim g_objWMIService

Set g_objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
Set colServices = g_objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT Version FROM SoftwareLicensingService")

For each objService in colServices
    Exit For
Next

objService.ClearProductKeyFromRegistry()

LineOut "Product key from registry cleared successfully."
```

Now, since we're using WMI, we need to reference the system.management assembly and add a using:

```
using System.Management;
```

And then it's just a matter of conversion. Some of this I haven't done before, but it should do the trick:

```
private static void ClearProductKeyFromRegistry()
{
    const string query = "SELECT Version FROM SoftwareLicensingService";
    var searcherProd = new ManagementObjectSearcher("\\\\.\\ROOT\\cimv2", query);
    var results = searcherProd.Get();

    foreach (ManagementObject result in results)
    {
        result.InvokeMethod("ClearProductKeyFromRegistry", null);
        break;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Product key from registry cleared successfully.");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally I discovered the way to invoke a method, seeying [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19033703/wmi-methods-using-managementobject-invokemethod). Then I just followed what I seen there, adapting it to my needs, so I wrote this useful code snippet developed in VB.NET:

```
''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
''' <summary>
''' Removes the Windows product key from registry (to prevent unauthorized diffusion). 
''' <para></para>
''' It does not uninstall the product key.
''' </summary>
''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
''' <remarks>
''' <see href="https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc534586(v=vs.85).aspx"/>
''' </remarks>
''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
''' <exception cref="PlatformNotSupportedException">
''' Windows 7 or newer is required to use this feature.
''' </exception>
''' 
''' <exception cref="Exception">
''' Unknown error occurred during the product key removal attempt.
''' </exception>
''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<DebuggerStepThrough>
Public Shared Sub RemoveWindowsProductKeyFromRegistry()

    ' If Not (WindowsUtils.IsWin7OrGreater) Then
    '     Throw New PlatformNotSupportedException("Windows 7 or newer is required to use this feature.")
    ' End If

    Using query As New ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM SoftwareLicensingService")

        For Each product As ManagementObject In query.Get()

            Dim result As UInteger
            Try
                result = CUInt(product.InvokeMethod("ClearProductKeyFromRegistry", Nothing))

            Catch ex As COMException
                Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(ex.HResult)

            Catch ex As Exception
                Throw

            End Try

            If (result <> 0UI) Then
                Throw New Exception("Unknown error occurred during the product key removal attempt.")
            End If

        Next product

    End Using

End Sub
```

Plus this other snippet to bring a way to programatically install a product key (it works on my machine with Windows 10, but probably it needs more testing):

```
''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
''' <summary>
''' Installs a Windows product key.
''' </summary>
''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
''' <remarks>
''' <see href="https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc534590(v=vs.85).aspx"/>
''' </remarks>
''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
''' <example> This is a code example.
''' <code>
''' Dim productKey As String = "YTMG3-N6DKC-DKB77-7M9GH-8HVXX"
''' InstallProductKey(productKey)
''' </code>
''' </example>
''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
''' <param name="productKey">
''' The product key.
''' </param>
''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
''' <exception cref="PlatformNotSupportedException">
''' Windows 7 or newer is required to use this feature.
''' </exception>
''' 
''' <exception cref="ArgumentNullException">
''' productKey
''' </exception>
''' 
''' <exception cref="Exception">
''' The Software Licensing Service determined that the product key is invalid.
''' or
''' Unknown error occurred during the product key installation attempt.
''' </exception>
''' ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<DebuggerStepThrough>
Public Shared Sub InstallProductKey(ByVal productKey As String)

    ' If Not (WindowsUtils.IsWin7OrGreater) Then
    '     Throw New PlatformNotSupportedException("Windows 7 or newer is required to use this feature.")
    ' End If

    Using query As New ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM SoftwareLicensingService")

        For Each product As ManagementObject In query.Get()

            Dim result As UInteger
            Try
                result = CUInt(product.InvokeMethod("InstallProductKey", {productKey}))
                product.InvokeMethod("RefreshLicenseStatus", Nothing)

            Catch ex As COMException When (ex.HResult = -1073418160)
                Throw New Exception("The Software Licensing Service determined that the product key is invalid.", ex)

            Catch ex As COMException
                Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(ex.HResult)

            Catch ex As Exception
                Throw

            End Try

            If (result <> 0UI) Then
                Throw New Exception("Unknown error occurred during the product key installation attempt.")
            End If

        Next product

    End Using

End Sub
```